error: error while writing JavaFXApplication3: could not create parent directories public class JavaFXApplication3 extends Application
i want to create a java FX project on NetBeans using java with ant
and it keeps showing me this error
i have updated java to latest update
i have reinstalled NetBeans to the latest update
and it still keeps showing me this error
